# Selecionar linha no datatable e obter id

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables

No jquery datatable como faço para selecionar uma única linha e obter o valor de determinada coluna, como por exemplo o id?

http://jsfiddle.net/miguelpacifico/4jjkrqew/

Comment: Pode colocar o código aqui , ou juntar um exemplo no jsFiddle por exemplo?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/miguelpacifico/4jjkrqew/

Answer (score 1):

Com esse código você irá pegar o conteúdo da coluna:

```
$('th').click(function(){
        alert($(this).html());
    });
```

Só precisa adaptar a sua necessidade.

Answer (score 0):

No seu código no Jsfiddle basta trocar o evento on-click do botão para este:

```
$('#btnGetId').click( function () {
    alert($('#example tr.selected').children(':first-child').html());
} );
```

O que está fazendo neste caso é pegando o valor existente dentro da primeira coluna, mas isto pode variar bastante.

Você poderia colocar o **id** da linha (**tr**) com o valor do campo id e poderia pegar da seguinte forma:

```
$('#btnGetId').click( function () {
    alert($('#example tr.selected').attr('id'));
} );
```

Ficando mais seguro, pois se você trocar a ordem das colunas o seu id vai continuar buscando do mesmo lugar.

Ou então adicionar uma classe específica para a coluna do id e podendo recuperar assim:

```
$('#btnGetId').click( function () {
    alert($('#example tr.selected').children('.id').html());
} );
```